# Servlet sessions in an android app

Tags: android, servlets

I'm currently making an android app that makes POST requests to a tomcat server which makes a session for the user, though the sessions seem to not be working. I'm getting a new session with each request. Is there any way to keep this session or track the user another way? The code for querying the server is generally as follows:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = HttpPostFactory.getHttpPost("AuthenticateUser");

    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option1", option1);
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option2", option2);

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            builder.append(in.nextLine());
        }

        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(MyStringUtil.toInputStream(builder.toString()));
```

I have full source code access to both the client and server, so a solution on either end will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep recreating your HttpClient; unless you have your own cookie store implementation that will keep cookies across instantiations or otherwise restores them, they'll keep going away.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html

Comment: Much appreciated! Worked like a charm! Only learnt how to make POST requests in java earlier today, so I still have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I believe tomcat uses a `JSESSIONID` to maintain sessions. This is stored as a cookie. In order to keep that same session alive, you'll need to send the cookies along with your next `HttpRequest`.